# C# read registry key, compare it to ini config file, if match return result under config section, do somethig else

Tags: c#, registry, ini

I got below problem and with my entry level of C# please help on how to get this be done?

Scenario:
1. My registry keys:

```
__DatabaseConnection
|____config1
     value: username1
     value: password1
|____config2
     value: username2
     value:password2
```

1. My ini file:

   [configz]

   Database=MSSQL
    DatabaseName= ABC
    Host=localhost\projects

   [config1]

   Database=ORACLE
    DatabaseName= DEF
    Host=server/data

   [configN]
    Name=xxxx
    Age=XXXX

Question:

I want to read those registry keys compare them to those configuration sections in ini file.

If match, return those value of database/ name/ host.
Connect to database server, delete the database.
Repeate the process until all keys in the registry is searched and all databases deleted.

Please help!
Best Regards,
Duy.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why are you using the registry *and* an ini file?

Comment: @leppie: I stuck completely, i think of array types, but can not imaging how it work :(

Comment: @Ed: my tasks at work required, i am not familiar with C#

Comment: Have a stab at it yourself.  You can easily find information on how to load and read text files and access the registry in C#.  If you have specific problems then feel free to ask them — but this is not a free version of rentacoder.

Answer (score 0):

For registry stuff in C# look here, particuarly the `GetValue()` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

```
public static Object GetValue(
    string keyName,
    string valueName,
    Object defaultValue
)
```

For reading IniFiles see this SO post: [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c)