# C# equivalent of Delphi's .INI-reading methods

Tags: c#, delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading/writing INI file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c-sharp)

What methods or C# libraries are available that can do something as below ? Thanks

```
   //Delphi read item in a given  section of a binary file.
   uses iniFiles; 
   readString('SectionName','itemName','DefaultValueIfNotFound');
```

Comment: use the System.Configuration class

Comment: When you move to .NET, better leave *.ini behind.

Comment: using app.config and web.config file will allow for more capability, power, and control you can even Encrypt portions of the app.config file it's not very hard to learn the use.. I have coded Delphi for 17 years and I picked up .NET very easy. keep in mind the guy that wrote C#.NET for Microsoft wrote Delphi for Borland, so you should be able to adapt to the cross over very rapidly.

Comment: Just a note: Your comment references a "binary" file, but an INI file isn't "binary" (it's text). Also, your code fragment is totally invalid; you don't declare or create an instance of `TIniFile` or `TMemIniFile`, nor do you reference one in the call to `ReadString`.

Comment: I was ironically wondering the exact same subject just before I saw this, but I had every plan to investigate Google before asking any questions. Also, INI files are not Delphi specific, so the real question is how to use INI files with C#.

Answer (score 9):

There aren't classes in the framework for reading INI files directly, as they are not really considered a good option now.  Instead, it's typically recommended that you use the [Application Settings infrastructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) or other more flexible techniques, such as saving information in XML files or databases.

However, many people have written their own libraries, such as [this one on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/INI_Files.aspx), which would allow you to easily read values from a section of an ini file in C#.

Comment: +1. Here's another possible CodeProject link [An INI file handling class in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_ini.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you really must then use this pinvoke method.

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetPrivateProfileString

INI files are old legacy and not recommended for use by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly the same as using Delphi's [TIniFile](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm), I've found the open-source [Nini library](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) to work well.

Here's an [example](http://nini.sourceforge.net/Manual/NiniManual-2.htm#ASimpleExample) of reading an INI file using Nini:

```
; MyApp.ini
[Logging]
File Name = MyApp.log
MessageColumns = 5
MaxFileSize = 40000000000000
```

Below is a C# example piece of code that describes how to access the configuration data from the INI file from the file above:

```
using Nini.Config;
IConfigSource source = new IniConfigSource("MyApp.ini");

string fileName = source.Configs["Logging"].Get("File Name");
int columns = source.Configs["Logging"].GetInt("MessageColumns");
long fileSize = source.Configs["Logging"].GetLong("MaxFileSize");
```