# Get specific elements from string file

Tags: c#

Hi all i'm reading a file into a string variable, however i'm wondering what the best way to return only a specific element in the string into a new variable.

I have the following string data file:

```
[TEST1]
mem.consumed.average = 965608688
cpu.usagemhz.average = 18653
Hosts = 3
Points = 1535
RAM = 1535.96
CPU = 191.79
Powered_on VMs = 70
Powered_on RAM = 1049.02
Powered_on CPU = 410.15
Powered_on Points = 1051
Provisioned VMs = 74
Provisioned RAM = 1057.02
Provisioned CPU = 416.59
Provisioned Points = 1059

[TEST2]
mem.consumed.average = 298762549
cpu.usagemhz.average = 7782
Hosts = 4
Points = 1535
RAM = 1535.96
CPU = 191.79
Powered_on VMs = 54
Powered_on RAM = 303.00
Powered_on CPU = 266.29
Powered_on Points = 303
Provisioned VMs = 60
Provisioned RAM = 330.00
Provisioned CPU = 295.28
Provisioned Points = 330
```

I only want to return the values for "Hosts", so in the case above only Hosts = 3 (from [TEST1]) and Hosts = 4 (from [TEST2]). Any ideas would be most appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading/writing INI file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just read line by line and look for `line.StartsWith("Hosts")` - when that is true, pull out what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just search it as a string, why not use .indexOf function.

So it would be

```
int a = data.indexOf('hosts');
int b = data.indexOf('points');
```

then

```
string hosts data = data.Substring(a,b);
```

you will have to alter the indexs to get the exact value out but it should be easy enough
Something like

```
string hosts data = data.Substring(a + 7,b - 2);
```