# how to create exe for c# desktop application

Tags: c#, deployment, sql-server-express

I am trying to create setup file for my desktop application.
I am using SQL Server Express as database and c# as programming language.
I searched about creating the setup file but i am having some doubts...
I have written the code to connect to the database in a class and called it wherever it is needed.

the code for creating connection is..

```
class dbConnection
{
    SqlConnection con;

    public SqlConnection doConnection()
    {

        try
        {
            String str = "Data Source=Basu-Pc\\SQL;Initial Catalog=PhoenixIS;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
            con = new SqlConnection(str);
            con.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

I call this class where ever I need it....and now I have some questions:

1. how do I modify the connection string in order to deploy it to other system?
2. how do I deploy sql express along with the system with hassle?

please help me get answer to my questions...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setup project as in this link:

[create setup project step by step](http://www.fordevs.com/2009/07/steps-to-create-setup-and-deployment-project-in-dot-net-vs-2008.html)

About the sql connection string, you just need to create a .ini file and read that file in your program as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c-sharp).

If you want to deploy sql express, just add the db file as resource in setup project.

HTH.

Comment: what about my connection string. how does it work ...or what should i do about it

Comment: you may go to www.connectionstrings.com to find appropriate string.