# Is it ok to use .ini files for storing data in .net windows application?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

An existing windows application(contain MS word add-in) with several controls has to be re-developed. previous application uses hundreds of ini files for storing data. Is it ok to use several ini files to store data? or should i create a database and store data there?

Comment: If you want to upgrade technology then use database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think .net supports ini files out the box, the new way to go is xml (config files)

This answer has few links to support inifiles: [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c-sharp)

If you need to upgrade a lot of versions in the field there is no reason not to continue with ini files. I personally don't mind the format.

Comment: i agree with u... in upgraded version nobody want to change ini file as data storage.they want it as it is.