# How to match a block of text with C# Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text file with hundreds of lines that follow this pattern:

```
[Part 1.SubPart 2.A 1]
Variable=value
(...)
LastVariable1=value
[Part 1.SubPart 2.B 2]
Variable=value
(...)
LastVariable2=value
[Part 1.SubPart 2.C 3]
Variable=value
(...)
LastVariable3=value
[Part 1.SubPart 3.A 1]
(...)
```

I need to extract each block that starts with **[Part...A *]** and ends before the next "A" block starts.

The very last variable "LastVariable3" has a constant name in all the Parts and can be ignored for my purposes.

I've tried using the following expressions based on other posts here, but they are not working.

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"\[Part.*A..\])(.*)(^LastVariable3)",RegexOptions.Singleline);

var pattern = new Regex(@"\[Part.*A..\])(.|\n)*(^LastVariable3)",RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

...they always match all the Part blocks in the WHOLE file at once instead of one at a time.

I've also tried   `(\[Part.*A..\]\n)(.*(\n)){"number of lines"}` but the number of variables are not constant so this won't work.

Hope this made sense!  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to Regex.

Comment: [Reading/writing INI file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is very close. You just forgot an extra paren (`)`). Also, you need to use `RegexOptions.Multiline` instead of `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

I've tried this pattern and it worked:

```
\[Part.*A..\](.|\n)*(^LastVariable3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` regex pattern

```
(\[Part\s[^\]]+\s\d+\.A\s\d+\].*?)(?=(?:[\n\r]\[Part\s[^\]]+\s\d+\.A\s\d+\]|\Z))
```