# How to use a wrapper class to parse values in ini file (windows phone 7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading/writing INI file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c-sharp)

my job is to parse the contents of an INI file. for this I want to use a wrapper function in which the input should be the section and key of the INI file and the output should be the corresponding value.

for example, if I give section name as "battery" and key name as "status", so I should get their corresponding value as stored in the INI file.

how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ini-parser library](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/).