# Finding where in a string a substring is with VB or C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

Basically what I'm doing is reading in a large input of data to put into a structure which then goes into a generic collection. What I am needing to do is search that large amount of input for certain strings (example of such would be something like "Option=value").

"Option=value" would be a part of a larger string that I've read into memory. I want to find if "Option=value" exists and where so that I can put that value into my structure.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: can you give sample string and your desired result?

Comment: It's more of a reading in of a text file. But it would look something like

`[data]`
`TextColor=Red`
`TextFont=Arial`


and so on and so forth.

Comment: Use `String.Contains("Option=value")`

Comment: The value I'm trying to extract is "TextColor=Red", keep in mind that what I gave is a small example, there could be 20-30 options in no particular order.

@Xaqron

That doesn't tell me WHERE in the string "Option=value" lives, so I cannot create a substring to import into my structure.

Comment: there is always `[data]` on it? can you post a little real text along with your question?

Comment: Are you looking for `String.IndexOf()` and `String.SubString()`? Or are you trying to access `.INI` format data? `[Section]`, followed by lines of `SomeOpt=SomeValue` pairs? If so, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/217902/62576) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12441567/62576).

Comment: You can find start point by `String.IndexOf("Option=value")` and use the result for subsequent `String.IndexOf("Option=value", previousIndex)`

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful to know what the input format is.  Html? INI? What?

Comment: Both Kevin White and Xaqron answered the question...excellent answers guys...thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf will return >-1 for both "Option=value" and "AlternativeOption=value" or "TextColor=Red" and "CommentTextColor=Red".

Therefore it is mandatory to incorporate separation characters while using IndexOf or depending on the input layout use Regex.

ie for options in the form "[option=value]" use

```
Regex.Matches(input, "[TextColor=Red]");
```

with or without RegexOptions or

```
input.IndexOf("[TextColor=Red]", start);
```