# How to import csv files with schema

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, excel-interop

I am looking for a way to import csv files with schma (.ini file).
I want import the csv into a datatable.
I don't want to use excel interop, because of known issues in running it on windows services.

Is there a way to do so in another tool or technology such as OpenXML?

I've already tested Aspose's and Syncfusion's tools  - and it seems they can't offer a solution here. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file ?

Comment: i am not looking for a way to read ini files. this is not a duplicate.I am looking for a way to export csv files with schema to datatable

Comment: OK, because in your question you ask how to "*import csv files with schma (.ini file)*" and don't speak of DataTable. So please fix to ease further research. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an ODBC connection, which treats the text file as a database. Just make sure the .ini file is in the same location as the text-file.

Recording a macro in Excel from the following steps will give you some base code to work with.

- Data > Import External Data > New Database Query

  1. Select  In Create New Data Source,
  2. choose a name
  3. select the driver - Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
  4. click Connect and in ODBC Text Setup select the folder containing the csv file
  5. select a default table - the csv file (optional)

A similar process can be coded in C# without using Interop. It just uses a database connection, probably `OleDbConnection`.