# Search rasphone pbk file

Tags: c#, .net, vpn

In my application I'm using the rasphone function to connect to vpn's When my application launches it gets all the vpn connections in a combobox using this code.

```
String f = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(f))
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                if (s.StartsWith("["))
                {
                    char[] MyChar = { ']' };
                    string NewString = s.TrimEnd(MyChar);
                    char[] MyChar2 = { '[' };
                    string NewString2 = NewString.TrimStart(MyChar2);
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(NewString2);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PBK File not found.");
        }
        comboBox1.Sorted = true;
```

Now my question is how I can also get the phonenumer= section to display in a textbox or label, so I know what the IP is.

A pbk file looks like this (had to delete some rows), the problem is that I have multiple vpn connections in the pbk file so also multiple phonenumer= entries.

```
[VPN Name of connection]
Encoding=1
PBVersion=3
Type=2


DEVICE=vpn
PhoneNumber= 0.0.0.0 <- ip address I want to display in a label or textbox.
AreaCode=
CountryCode=0
CountryID=0
UseDialingRules=0
Comment=
FriendlyName=
LastSelectedPhone=0
PromoteAlternates=0
TryNextAlternateOnFail=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a very simple solution and I understand your question correctly this should do the trick, add the following statement after your current `if` in your `foreach` statement

```
else if(str.Contains("PhoneNumber"))
{
    var x = str.Split('=');
    if(x.Length > 1)
    ip = x[1];
}
```

Please note that `ip` is the variable were you would like to store your IP-address.

To answer your question in the comments and assuming that you always have a [VPN-Connection] before each PhoneNumber entry you could write something like this

```
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            if (s.StartsWith("["))
            {
                char[] MyChar = { ']' };
                string NewString = s.TrimEnd(MyChar);
                char[] MyChar2 = { '[' };
                string NewString2 = NewString.TrimStart(MyChar2);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(NewString2);
            }
            else if (s.Contains("PhoneNumber"))
            {
                string ip = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.Items.Count - 1].ToString() + " : ";
                var x = s.Split('=');
                if (x.Length > 1)
                    ip += x[1];
            }
        }
```

This would get the item that were last added to the combobox and put it before the string of the ip address, still just a simple hack but it is one way to do it.. if you have more advanced needs I would make a class to store the data that you require and the populate the combobox from that.

Comment: how can I make this so it starts searching for Phonenumber= ipadress in the pbk file after the given [vpn connection]?

Answer (score 0):

well. you could read the file contents and use regex to extract it with

```
PhoneNumber=(?<ip>[^\n]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can p/invoke [`RasGetEntryProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377535(v=vs.85).aspx) passing it the pbk file, or you can simply parse out the value from the text file. Its in INI format and there are many [INI File reader classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file) out there.