# Parse key=value with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have simple text:

```
first_name=value1
secon_name=value2
date_b = 12.01.1989
```

Rows is separated by `\n` char. I have code which split this string and then I iterate through array and check the keys:

```
string[] data = str.Split('\n');
foreach (var row in data)
{
   if (row.StartsWith("first_name"))
   {
       obj.FirstName = row.Remove(0, ("first_name").Length);
       ...
   }
}
```

But there are about 15 pairs and the code in `foreach` very unreadable. How to parse this with regular expression? I want to get `dictionary<key, value>`.

PS. Some rules:
1. The key is without whitespace.
2. The value can contain whitespace.

Comment: No need for regex. Split each line with `=`

Comment: @L.B Well, the first `=`, just in case value can contain an `=` sign. Either way, this is simple text parsing - there are an infinite amount of samples of this online.

Comment: what about `Regex.Split(str,"\s*=\s*")`

Comment: Related ini parsing pages? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095343/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/217902/2943403

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(.*?)\s*=\s*([^\s]+)
```

This should work.Will give you groups containing both the matches.

Have a look.

http://regex101.com/r/wE3dU7/4