# Get parameters from text file c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file that is formatted like so...

```
[Dimensions]
Height=100
Width=200
Depth=1000
```

I am trying to write a method that takes the parameter name such as `"Height"` with the text and returns the value of the parameter but it is currently not working

```
public int getParameter(data, param) {
        var start = data.IndexOf(param);
        var end = data.IndexOf('\r\n', start);
        return data.Substring(start + param.length + 1, end);
    }
```

But it always returns partial text on the next line such as

> "100\r\nWid"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why are you still using INI format instead of XML?

Comment: I have no choice in the data format.

Comment: Read file line by line. Create collection where keep key as Hight, width, depth and values as values. And search in this preapared collection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use a regular expression for that:

```
public int getParameter(string data, string param) {
        var expr = "^" + param + @"=(\d+)\r?$";
        var match = Regex.Match(data, expr, 
                                  RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
         // NB - can remove the option to IgnoreCase if desired
        return match == null || !match.Success ? default(int) : int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong value to second parameter for `Substring`.It's the `lenght`, not the end index, so it should be:

```
var startIndex = start + param.length + 1;

return data.Substring(startIndex, end - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to parse an ini file, for which there are already [some options avaiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file).

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty similar to TOML, you might want to do minor changes and use the [TOML.NET Package](https://github.com/rossipedia/toml-net).

I didn't test it, but used TOML in a go project and it worked quite well. Takes some effort from yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That file follows the ini format, so I'll recommend using ini-parser for reading it: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser

Is as simple as:

```
   var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
   IniData parsedData = parser.LoadFile("config.ini");
   int height = Int32.parse(parsedData["Height"])
```

Disclaimer, I'm the author of the library