# C# find variables within a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that contains the following information

```
[Messaging]
    Gatekeeper = "${Const|BaseURL}:${Const|PublicPort}"

[AvatarService]
    AvatarServerURI = "${Const|BaseURL}:${Const|PrivatePort}"
```

How do i look in the string for gatekeeper and out put the value of gatekeeper?

so ex
looking in string for `gatekeeper` should produce result of `${Const|BaseURL}:${Const|PrivatePort}`  with no quotes.

Comment: What you have here is an `.ini` file. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14906422/561113) for how to use it.

Comment: this is not in an ini file, this is settings sent from a server,http://andromedagrid.com:8002/get_sim_info

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to extract the settings :

```
var settings = Regex.Split(settings_received_from_server, @"(?=\[\w+\])")
    .ToDictionary(
        section => Regex.Match(section, @"\[(?<section>\w+)\]").Groups["section"].Value,
        section => section.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            // remove empty line or section header
            .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\[.+\]"))
            // see note below
            .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.+)"))
            .ToDictionary(
                match => match.Groups["key"].Value,
                match => match.Groups["value"].Value));

// to get the setting use the following : [section][key]
settings["AvatarService"]["AvatarServerURI"]
```

Note: By default the double-quot is kept, in case you also have unquoted value.

If you like to remove the double-quotes, use the following regex :

```
@"(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*\""(?<value>.+)\"""
```