# How to read setting from INI-file

Tags: c#

I have a text file `installer.ini` where I have a row who is like : `fileExecutable=D:\location`. I want to get the text after `=` and put in a variable. After that I want to use that variable instead of `D:\location` in code.

```
    foreach (var txt in lin)
    {
        if (txt.Contains("fileExecutable="))
        {
            var ExeFile = txt.Split('=')[1];
        }
    }
    // The installer itself 
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\location";                       
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-if C:\temp\installer.ini";
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

I try to put in the variable `ExeFile` what I have in text file after `fileExecutable=`and use that variable in this row: `process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\location";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `ExeFile` is declared inside the `foreach` loop and is therefore not useable after the loop. If you move it outside the loop you can use it after the loop.

```
var ExeFile = String.Empty;
foreach (var txt in lin)
{
    if (txt.Contains("fileExecutable="))
    {
        ExeFile = txt.Split('=')[1];
    }
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ExeFile))
{
   // The installer itself 
   process.StartInfo.FileName = ExeFile;                       
   process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-if C:\temp\installer.ini";
   process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit();
}
```

**EDIT** Alternative

You can you use a regelar expression on the whole INI-file to skip looping through all lines like so:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        // dummy ini for testing.
        var ini = "test\nfileExecutable=D:\\location\ntest";

        var regex = new Regex("^fileExecutable=(.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var location = regex.Match(ini).Groups[1];

        Console.WriteLine(location);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Yet another alternative

After editing the title of your question it came to me you might want to read other settings from the ini as well. If so, consider using an INI-reader as discussed here: [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)

Comment: And is a way to do this thing without use foreach ?

Comment: Use linq query instead of foreach

Comment: `var ExeFile = lin.Where(txt => txt.Contains("fileExecutable=")).Select(txt => txt.Split('=')[1]).FirstOrDefault();`