# Regex Retrieving String within String

Tags: c#, regex, ini

I have these two strings:

```
 s = t 
 [ f ] s = t
```

and processing each with regex using this pattern:

```
(?<=]).*(?==|:)
```

My goal is trying to retrieve the `" s " part (between the "]" and "=")`, though the `"[ f ]" is optional`, as you can see in the first line.

I've tried many different patterns found online and used by others, also spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out with references, search engines, trial and error, but to no success.

How would I achieve this? What pattern would I need to achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here? A single example doesn't cut it.

Comment: If your goal is to parse ini file, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex for this task. Basically, the `s` must be some string of text between `]` or start of line/string and a `=` symbol.

So, use

```
(?:^\p{Zs}*|])([^]=]*)=
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A%5E%5Cp%7BZs%7D*%7C%5D)(%5B%5E%5D%3D%5D*)%3D&i=%20%5B%20f%20%5D%20s%20%3D%20t%0D%0As%20%3D%20t%20%0D%0A%20%5B%20f%20%5D%20s%20%3D%20t%0D%0As%20%3D%20t%20%0D%0As%20%3D%20t%20&o=m)

The regex breakdown:

- `(?:^\p{Zs}*|])` - a non-capturing group matching 2 alternatives:

  - `^\p{Zs}*` - start of string/line (depends on `RegexOptions` used) followed by 0 or more horizontal whitespace symbols or...
  - `]` - a literal `]` symbol
- `([^]=]*)` - (Capture Group 1) 0 or more symbols that are not `]` or `=`.
- `=` -  a literal `=` symbol

[C# Code](http://ideone.com/zIIg3Y):

```
var strs = new List<string> { " [ f ] s = t", "s = t"};
var pattern = @"(?:^\p{Zs}*|])([^]=]*)=";
foreach (var s in strs)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
   }
```

If you need to get the value you need via `Match.Value`, you can use

```
@"(?<=^\p{Zs}*|])[^]=:]*(?=[=:])"
```

Here is the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cp%7BZs%7D*%7C%5D)%5B%5E%5D%3D%3A%5D*(%3F%3D%5B%3D%3A%5D)&i=%20%5B%20f%20%5D%20s%20%3D%20t%0D%0As%20%3D%20t%20%0D%0A%20%5B%20f%20%5D%20s%20%3D%20t%0D%0As%20%3D%20t%20%0D%0As%20%3D%20t%20&o=m)

Comment: Is there an extra bit to get rid of the ] and = at the start and end, I realize I could just substring at this point, just wondered.

Comment: But you do not get them in the `Groups[1].Value`. If you need to get the `s` as a `match.Value`, you can use a much less efficient `var pattern = @"(?<=^\p{Zs}*|])[^]=]*(?==)";`.

Comment: I'm using .value, but it also gets the ] and =, I don't mind substringing, how about if the = sign was a colon or an equals?

Comment: The value you need can be obtained by accessing `match.Groups[1].Value` with my original answer, it is possible due to the capturing group (round brackets) in the pattern that *captures* a part of the matched substring into a separate buffer. It is best practice to use capturing groups where lookarounds turn out inefficient. But the regex in my  previous comment should work for you well even with `match.Value`.

Comment: It worked! [regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cp%7bZs%7d*%7c%5d)%5b%5e%5d%3d%3a%5d*(%3f%3d%3d%7c%3a)&i=+%5b+f+%5d+s+%3d+t%0d%0as+%3d+t+%0d%0a+%5b+f+%5d+s+%3d+t%0d%0as+%3d+t+%0d%0as+%3d+t+%0d%0as%3at%0d%0as+%3a+t%0d%0a+s+%3a+t+%0d%0a+%5b+f+%5d+s+%3a+t+&o=m)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using RegEx, why not use regular .NET methods? Always remember that **regular expressions aren't silver bullets**. An operation that takes a few lines of code can quickly become a convoluted mess in RegEx.

Your case can be solved by the following function:

```
static string GetKey(string line)
{
    string result = line.Split('=')[0];
    if (result.IndexOf('[') < result.IndexOf(']')) // preceded by an optional group
        result = result.Split(']')[1];

    return result;
}
```

Running your code through this function successfully retrieves the `s` on each line.

Comment: Yours is an answer, a good one, though I purposely wanted to keep lines down to minimal for my own reasons, so I wanted to use regex for those reasons.