# C# Reading from file

Tags: c#, .net, file, streamreader

it is project to Learn cause i love coding
i`m trying to read from file that got Shape Like below
i must read [] sections and take every element under it
and it is ini format

```
  [Connection]
    IP=
    LoginPort=
    Locale=
    Version=
    [Client]
    Username=xxx
    Password=xxx
    CharName=xxx
    Captcha=

    [MASTER]
    Master=
    [Buffs]
    //[Comment...........]
    Buff1=9460
    Buff2=10078
    Buff3=
    Buff4=
    Buff5=
    Buff6=
    Buff7=
    //[Comment...........]
```

Comment: its seems INI file format..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file