# How to process this text block by block?

Tags: c#, text-files, block, sequencefile

I want to process the data block by block separately

Here is the text:

[Global]
asd
dsa
akl
ASd

[Test2]
bnmnb
hkhjk
tzutzi
Tzutzi
Tzitzi

[Test3]
5675
46546
464
564
56456
45645654
4565464

[other]
sdfsd
dsf
sdf
dsfs

And first I want the first block and process it than the second... etc..

```
private void textprocessing(string filename)
{
    using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        string linetemp = "";
        bool found = false;
        int index = 0;

        while ((linetemp=sr1.ReadLine())!=null)
        {
            if (found==true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(linetemp);
                break;   
            }

            if (linetemp.Contains("["))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                found = false;
            }                                                             
        }                                    
    }          
}
```

Comment: is that an .ini file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string.Split() to split your strings based on "[" then split that based on newlines. THen you check for the presence of "]"

```
void Main()
{
    string txt = @"[Global]
asd
dsa
akl
ASd

[Test2]
bnmnb
hkhjk
tzutzi
Tzutzi
Tzitzi

[Test3]
5675
46546
464
564
56456
45645654
4565464

[other]
sdfsd
dsf
sdf
dsfs";

    string[] split = txt.Split('[');
    foreach(var s in split)
    {
        var subsplits = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine(subsplits[0]);
        foreach(var ss in subsplits)
        {
            if(!ss.Contains("]"))
                Console.WriteLine(ss);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
asd
dsa
akl
ASd


bnmnb
hkhjk
tzutzi
Tzutzi
Tzitzi


5675
46546
464
564
56456
45645654
4565464


sdfsd
dsf
sdf
dsfs
```

You could add an aditional check to check if it's a blank line and ignore it.

Comment: It is a good solution, but I want to solve it with cycle and without built in function like split, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
private void ReadFile()
{
    //load all  lines
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\file.txt").ToList().;
    //remove empty lines
    lines = lines.Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0).ToList();
    //mark indexes where sections start
    var sectionIndexes = lines
        .Where(l => l.StartsWith("[") && l.EndsWith("]"))
        .Select(l => lines.IndexOf(l)).ToList();

    //now make list of tuples. Each tuple contains start of section (Item1) and last line of section (Item2)
    var sections = Enumerable.Zip(sectionIndexes, sectionIndexes.Skip(1), (a, b) => new Tuple<int, int>(a, b-1)).ToList();

    //for each tuple (each section)
    foreach (var item in sections)
    {
        //process section name (line with raound brackets
        ProcessSection(lines[item.Item1], lines.Where(l => lines.IndexOf(l) > item.Item1 && lines.IndexOf(l) <= item.Item2));
    }
}

private void ProcessSection(string sectionName, IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is section {0} with following lines: {1}", sectionName, string.Join(", ", lines.ToArray()));
}
```

output of `ProcessSection` method would be:

```
this is section [Global] with following lines: asd, dsa, akl, ASd
this is section [Test2] with following lines: bnmnb, hkhjk, tzutzi, Tzutzi, Tzitzi
this is section [Test3] with following lines: 5675, 46546, 464, 564, 56456, 45645654, 4565464
```

This is pretty quick and dirty solution, but it would suffice if file you're reading is small.

If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.