# C# Read specific property from a log file

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my M.U.G.E.N tournament program, I want to process the match results from the log file, that is created **by the game**. The log looks like this:

```
[Match 1]
totalmatches = 1
team1.1 = 
team2.1 = 
stage = stages/kowloon.def

[Match 1 Round 1]
winningteam = 1
timeleft = -1.00
p1.name = Knuckles the Echidna
p1.life = 269
p1.power = 0
p2.name = Shadow the Hedgehog
p2.life = 0
p2.power = 2684

[Match 1 Round 2]
winningteam = 2
timeleft = -1.00
p1.name = Knuckles the Echidna
p1.life = 0
p1.power = 1510
p2.name = Shadow the Hedgehog
p2.life = 586
p2.power = 2967

[Match 1 Round 3]
winningteam = 2
timeleft = -1.00
p1.name = Knuckles the Echidna
p1.life = 0
p1.power = 3000
p2.name = Shadow the Hedgehog
p2.life = 789
p2.power = 777
```

What I want is to process the last `winningteam` property to determine the result of the match. What is the most effective way to achieve this? (maybe with LINQ)

Comment: please provide "a way" that you already tried to use in order to achieve this. How are you reading the file? How do you get the different lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadLines` that returns an enumeration of lines as `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
// string path contains file path and file name.
string line = File.ReadLines(path)
    .LastOrDefault(ln => ln.StartsWith("winningteam ="));
```

Now split the string at `=`, trim the second part and you have the team number as string

```
if (line != null) {
    string team = line.Split('=')[1].Trim();
    // With "winningteam = 2", [0] = "winningteam ", [1] = " 2"

    // Optionally convert it to a number
    int teamNo = Int32.Parse(team);

    ...
}
```