# xml.Load - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I was recently working on a project that required using Xml so I naturally used LINQ-to-XML to load my documents.

Unfortunately, as soon as I used the XDocument.Load method, I encountered this dreaded error message:

> Data at the root level is invalid.  Line 1, position 1.

This error is thrown only in prod environment but not in local

```
doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Documents\\analyse\\InterBatch.ini");

XElement rootNode = doc.Element(Constant.NODE_CONFIGURATION);

fichierInstall.Base = this.ReadNodeBase(rootNode, Constant.NODE_BASE);
fichierInstall.Log = this.ReadNodeLog(rootNode, Constant.NODE_LOG);
fichierInstall.PathEntree = this.ReadNodePathEntree(rootNode, Constant.NODE_PATH_ENTREE);
fichierInstall.PathSortie = this.ReadNodePathSortie(rootNode, Constant.NODE_PATH_SORTIE);
```

any idea about the issue?

thank you

Comment: `InterBatch.ini` does not look like its an XML file ...  If it does actually contain XML what does it look like?

Comment: the file looks like `code`[Base]
ConnectionStringOracleSIG = "dsn=SIG;uid=USER_AS;pwd=USER_AS"
ConnectionStringOracle = "dsn=UTASS;uid=UTASS_user;pwd=UTASS_user"
[PathEntree]
PathFichier = "D:\wwwroot\Donnees\EnEcriture\Batch\Sortie\relance.dat"
[PathSortie]
PathFichier = "D:\WWWRoot\Donnees\EnEcriture\Sortie\Relance_UT_Fac.txt"
[Log]
CheminLog = "D:\WWWRootLog\" `code`

Comment: Well that's an INI file not an XML file - they are completely different formats. [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)

Comment: this is why the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes, the *"Data at the root level is invalid"* error is because XDocument expects XML but your giving it something completely different that it can't understand.