# Is there a way to load data from an ini file when writing a test case?

Tags: c#, testing, xunit

I need to pull data from a ".ini" file for the test case to operate on. Which of the three: `[InlineData]`, `[ClassData]` or `[MemberData]` attribute is best to use? I'm relatively new to C# programming, kindly bear with me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to execute some code to load your data, you can rule out `InlineData` (this one is to write constant values directly above the test method).

You an use either `ClassData` or `MemberData`, really. Refer to [the documentation](https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/) on how to use them, and then ask another question if you have a more precise issue.

To read an ini file, you can refer to [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file).

As a hint, you can get the full filepath when executing the test like this, if the ini file "myFile.ini" is at the root of your project :  `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myFile.ini")`.

Also, don't forget to select a "Copy" property as action for your ini file, in the solution.