# How to change the Application scoped value (Settings) without changing it from MyProgam.exe.config?

Tags: c#, .net, settings, configuration-files, application-settings

I have a project(Log) where I used application scope setting(LogLevel) in settings like below which shows the default value:
[image]

But now I have used the DLL of this project(**Log.dll**) in another project(**MyProgam** through reference) where I want to change the **Log Level value**. currently it's taking **3** by default as it is saved in Log.dll and I can change the value of LogLevel in second project by updating the value in MyProgam.exe.config.

As per my understanding the application settings come from **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile** by default which resulted **MyProgam.exe.config** in my case.

in config it shows like :

`<setting name="LogLevel" serializeAs="String">
                <value>3</value>
    </setting>`

So My question is, I want to make the change in LogLevel value (0/1/2) from second project but not through MyProgam.exe.config

Comment: or simply use (idc[system ini pharser for c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file))

Comment: @T.Dat : Could you please explain more? What is INI and how is it related to changing the application settings value?