# I'm using Danny Beckett's tiny Ini file, and it is working great. However, I'd like to store a historical list of recent files. Can this be added?

Tags: dictionary, ini

As mentioned in the title, I'm using Danny Beckett's ini file class defined here: [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)

It works really great, and met all my initial requirements. However, I'd really like to be able to access a section and read all the key/value pairs in that section into a list/dictionary. Using this method, I could store my recent output history into the ini file.

In my case, it would list vendors/suppliers, and the last time my application updated their price lists in our database. Each entry would consist of the vendors name as the key, and a date string that indicates the last update for that vendor.

I know I can write a simple log file to do this, but it would be a nice add to the existing functionality.

I cannot think of how exactly to write the method that would read the whole section of keys and values, but it would be great if it returned a dictionary.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ReadSection(string Section)
{
    var RetVal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    // code to read the section and add it to dictionary
    return RetVal;
}
```

Comment: The document you linked to includes this text: "The creators of the .NET framework want you to use XML-based config files, rather than INI files." I don't if that is true but the legacy INI file format is awful.

Comment: For what it is worth, I tried using Microsoft's solution to config files and it is by far the most frustrating exercise I have ever had. I could read the values but could not update them from within the application. Completely FUBAR.
The legacy INI format works fine for the low-security non-critical applications I am writing these days.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by iterating through a list of all parties in the database and checking to see if each one had an entry in the ini file. Every time I processed records for a party, I would write the date to the ini file with their partyId as the key. In this way I was able to retain a history in the ini file of the last time I updated prices for each party.

Here's the pertinent portions of the code:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> history = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public static List<string> partyList = new List<string>();

private void btnViewHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    history.Clear();
    // iterate through list of all parties in database
    // check to see if each one has a history entry
    // if so, add it to the list of entries
    foreach (string party in partyList)
    {
        var historyRecord = MyIni.Read(party, "History");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(historyRecord))
        {
            history.Add(party, historyRecord);
        }
    //... bind list to DataGridView on form and show form ...
    }
}
```